# How to improve my log class

Tags: c#, java

I have a log tool for my applications. I log to XML in a hierarchical manner (this means that I can nest log items). My `Log(string, bool)` takes two parameters, one with the string to log and a bool value determining if this comment should be nested below the previous log comment. A `PopLog()` method is made to go to the parent, and continue logging on the parent level.

This means that when I log like this:

```
Log("first", false);
...
Log("Second", true);
...
Log("Third", true);
PopLog();
PopLog();
PopLog();
```

This gives the following result:

```
<first>
  <second>
    <third>
  </second>
</first>
```

The problem I have with the current design is it is hard to keep track of my log level, how deep I am in the logging tree, and whether or not I need to pop, log using true, or log using false.

Any good ideas on how to make this simpler, more maintainable and better (changing log provider is not an option)?

Comment: Why you are not using log4net or log4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better design would be, IMO, to separate the push/pop behaviour from the logging itself. Here's a solution in C#, using `IDisposable`:

```
 class IndentedLog : IDisposable
 {
    public IndentedLog() 
    {
       Log.IndentLevel++; 
    }
    public void Dispose() 
    {
       Log.IndentLevel--;
    }
 }
```

This way, you can do something like:

```
     Log("first");
     // ...
     using (new IndentedLog())
     {
         Log("second");
         // ...
         using (new IndentedLog()) 
         {
            Log("third");
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add,  *for readability*, the possibility to `AddLog()` like a child. Fore example:

`Log("first").Log("second").Log("third")`

This basically means that `log()` should return a `content log` type.

Hope was clear, sorry but writing from mobile so write some concrete code example is a mess, but just to give a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add XPath expression instead of bool value

```
Log("first", "/first");
Log("Second", "/first/second");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `PopLog()` should be optional and only called when you know you require to go one level up. Otherwise at the end of execution `CloseAllTags()` should be called that closes all the open tags. If there are no open tags, `PopLog()` should do nothing.
This way you would not need to keep tabs on the nesting level.

Answer (score 0):

From within your log class you can have 3 properties: 
1. ID, which is unique to every instance.
2. Level, which is an int type that will describe how deep your log is.
3. Parent, that will be the ID of the log which is one level above in the xml.

Then you can write some method that will allow you to identify where the log resides and how deep it is using the above properties.